# Unable to Locate and Delete Items inside a Table using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

> Hello Everyone, I am facing a situation where I need to locate and remove items from a table from a website (https://jobassam.in/indian-army-recruitment-rally-mariani-jorhat/). Here is `screenshot` for better clearance :

[image]

> How to remove every `<tr>` below the Text **OUR SOCIAL CONNECTIONS** including the Text as well. This is the `HTML` structure of the Table :

[image]

> The `Arrow` in the Second Image is where the Text is Present. Also, this is the Code i wrote to Locate this elements and delete them :

```
 getDetails = soup2.find('div', class_='entry-content single-content')
 getTables = getDetails.find_all('table')
 for i in getTables:
   print(i.tr)
   i.decompose()
```

> But, the Issue is these Elements are still there. How to achieve this, Please Guide. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the index of the text you want to remove and start decomposing it from there.

So first lets get the table we're interested:

```py
working_table = next((table for table in getTables if table.text.find("OUR SOCIAL CONNECTIONS") != -1), None)
```

Then lets iterate over all `tr` on there to search for our item index to cut off:

```py
tables_itens = working_table.find_all('tr')
cut_line = [tables_itens.index(i) for i in tables_itens if i.text == "OUR SOCIAL CONNECTIONS"][0]
```

Then we start decomposing from there:

```py
for tr in tables_itens:
    if tables_itens.index(tr) >= cut_line:
        tr.decompose()
```

We can simply check this with:

```py
for i in tables_itens:
    print(i.text)
```

And it will ouput:

```
Download Official NotificationClick Here
Online Application LinkClick Here
Visit Official WebsiteClick Here
```

#### Full code:

```py
getDetails = soup2.find('div', class_='entry-content single-content')
getTables = getDetails.find_all('table')

working_table = next((table for table in getTables if table.text.find("OUR SOCIAL CONNECTIONS") != -1), None)

tables_itens = working_table.find_all('tr')
cut_line = [tables_itens.index(i) for i in tables_itens if i.text == "OUR SOCIAL CONNECTIONS"][0]

for tr in tables_itens:
    if tables_itens.index(tr) >= cut_line:
        tr.decompose()

for i in tables_itens:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: The Position of the Table is not guaranteed.It may be in second, third or fourth place. How to deal with situations like that ?

Comment: You can use the same text to select your table. I've updated the answer to match this.

Comment: Got it. Thank You !